# Renaming a single element in a select dropdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, frontend

In a Rails app, I've got an array that is a list of entry types: `["steps", "calories", "water", "sodium", "sugar", "fruits_veggies"]`

In my view, I'm creating a select box to choose one of the above entry types: `.controls= f.select :type, entry_type_options`

This works just fine, but I'd like to replace "fruits_veggies" with "fruits & veggies" in the dropdown box.  How can I do this for a single value?  options_for_select looked promising, but I'm not sure what route to take.

Note that I'm using a helper for "entry_type_options":

```
def entry_type_options                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  @entry_type_options ||= Entry::TYPES.map {|t| [t.capitalize, t] }                                                                                                                                                                     
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a case of being up too late.  I just changed the helper:

```
 def entry_type_options                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   @entry_type_options ||= Entry::TYPES.map {|t| (t == "fruits_veggies") ? ["Fruits & Veggies", t] : [t.capitalize, t]}                                                                                                                  
 end
```

Comment: I would rather create a static function in the Entry class that would return what you are doing in the helper.